# Issue with GWT SuggestBox

Tags: java, gwt, suggestbox

I'm experiencing some problems adding a `SuggestBox` to my application. The `UiBinder` template looks like:

```
...
<g:FlowPanel>
   <g:SuggestBox ui:field='actorSuggestBox' styleName='{style.givemespace}' />
   <g:Button ui:field="addActorButton">Add Actor</g:Button>
</g:FlowPanel>

<g:FlexTable ui:field='actorsTable'></g:FlexTable>
....
```

and I am creating my own suggestBox by extending **`MultiWordSuggestOracle`**. I have debugged my code and made sure that the custom `SuggestBox` class gets created and initialized properly before I initialize the `UiBinder`.

My `SuggestBox` doesn't work well. What puzzles me is that if I add it to the `FlexTable` (that I had to show entries I was adding via the suggestbox) using `setWidget(row, column, widget)` this component works properly, so probably I am missing something when initializing the UI. Although I have Dewsbury' book on GWT app, it does not cover `UiBinder`. The tutorials and code examples I have checked use

```
<g:SuggestBox ui:field="mySuggestBox"/>
```

with no problem. Yet, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong when creating and initializing this component or the UI that makes the `SuggestBox` not to work. I don't know if it takes more than

```
actorSuggestBox = new SuggestBox(new CustomSuggestOracle());
```

to initialize the sugestbox or if there is any other important concept that I am missing when linking/initializing this component.

The component is declared as

```
@UiField 
@Ignore
SuggestBox actorSuggestBox;
```

Comment: How do you declare actorSuggestBox in your code?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, I edited the question to address this. I use Ignore because the text of the SuggestBox is no _per se_ a field in my DTO. I read in some tutoriasl that I had to use (provided=true) but that made my code crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
@UiField (provided = true)
SuggestBox actorSuggestBox = new SuggestBox(new CustomSuggestOracle());
```

You need to initialize this widget before you call the binder (`createAndBindUi`).